# how to identify top of the hour in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cron

need some help to identify top of the hour in a shell script? I have a cron which runs and execute a shell script in every 10 minutes but I don't want this script to be run on top of the hour. so I am trying to skip the execution from script by checking top of the hour

Comment: You can use comma-separated lists in the crontab. List all the minutes when the job should run. When in doubt, see `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: You can also put it in the "range/step" format such that the bottom/start of the hour (same as the top of the hour; '0' in both cases) is not included. (And yes, I'm leaving it up to the OP to _read_ `man 5 crontab` to see how to do "range/step" formats.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's better to leave scheduling decisions to cron or other processes outside of the thing being scheduled.

Use a cron schedule that runs your script or code every 10 minutes, in such a way that it avoids running on the hour:

```
10,20,30,40,50 * * * * my-command-here
```

This is much more convenient than trying to make your *script* detect when it's being run.  It also would not affect *manual use* of your script.

Depending on your cron implementation, you could *possibly* use

```
10-50/10 * * * * my-command-here
```

which would run the job every ten minutes from 10 past the hour until 50 past the hour (i.e., it would skip the full hour).

Or even just

```
10/10 * * * * my-command-here
```

i.e., every ten minutes from 10 past the hour to 59 past the hour.

You would need to test whether the syntax in these last two examples is valid on your system, and I would suggest that you read your `crontab(5)` manual (`man 5 crontab`).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, the following `bash` script will skip the "top of the hour", but [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646492/286615) is more efficient - it's a better answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nowminute=$(date +%M)
topofhr="00"
if [ $nowminute == $topofhr ]; then exit 0; fi 

...

balance of your script
```

`date +%M` gets the **minute** from current value of the `date`; after that it's a comparison to see if it's the "top of the hour" (00 minutes).